# Unable to start nginx service via Chef

Tags: nginx, centos, chef-infra, chef-solo, knife-solo

I'm trying to start nginx using chef solo but keep getting the error below.

#### error

```
 * service[nginx] action start

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `start` on resource 'service[nginx]'
    ================================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
    ---- Begin output of /sbin/service nginx start ----
    STDOUT: Starting nginx: [FAILED]
    STDERR: nginx: [emerg] open() "/home/deploy/apps/...-api/shared/log/nginx.access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
    ---- End output of /sbin/service nginx start ----
    Ran /sbin/service nginx start returned 1

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /root/chef-solo/cookbooks-3/.../recipes/nginx.rb

     60: service 'nginx' do
     61:   action [:enable, :start]
     62: end

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /root/chef-solo/cookbooks-3/.../recipes/nginx.rb:60:in `from_file'

    service("nginx") do
      action [:enable, :start]
      supports {:restart=>nil, :reload=>nil, :status=>nil}
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      service_name "nginx"
      enabled true
      pattern "nginx"
      declared_type :service
      cookbook_name :...
      recipe_name "nginx"
    end


Running handlers:
[2016-01-22T18:28:41+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2016-01-22T18:28:41+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 11 resources updated in 25 seconds
[2016-01-22T18:28:41+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-01-22T18:28:41+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2016-01-22T18:28:41+00:00] ERROR: service[nginx] (...::nginx line 60) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /sbin/service nginx start ----
STDOUT: Starting nginx: [FAILED]
STDERR: nginx: [emerg] open() "/home/deploy/apps/...-api/shared/log/nginx.access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
---- End output of /sbin/service nginx start ----
Ran /sbin/service nginx start returned 1
[2016-01-22T18:28:41+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
ERROR: RuntimeError: chef-solo failed. See output above.
```

#### nginx.rb

```
include_recipe 'yum'

yum_repository 'nginx' do
  baseurl 'http://nginx.org/packages/centos/6/$basearch/'
  gpgcheck false
  enabled true
  action :create
end

yum_package 'nginx' do
  options '--enablerepo=nginx'
  action :install
end

# remove default nginx config
# default_path = '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default'
# execute "rm -f #{default_path}" do
#   only_if { File.exist?(default_path) }
# end

directory '/etc/nginx/sites-available' do
  owner 'deploy'
  group 'deploy'
  mode '0755'
  recursive true
  action :create
end

directory '/home/deploy/apps/...-api/current/public' do
  owner 'deploy'
  group 'deploy'
  mode '0755'
  recursive true
  action :create
end

cookbook_file '/etc/nginx/sites-available/default' do
  source 'nginx'
  owner 'deploy'
  group 'deploy'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end

directory '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled' do
  group 'deploy'
  mode '0755'
  owner 'deploy'
end

# set custom nginx config
cookbook_file '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf' do
  source 'nginx-base'
  owner 'deploy'
  group 'wheel'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end

service 'nginx' do
  action [:enable, :start]
end
```

Comment: Btw any arguments why the [nginx](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/nginx)  cookbook doesn't work for you?

Comment: @StephenKing I'm using CentOS and by default it install a very old version of nginx. As for the cookbook, I'm rather new to Chef and still get lost in the docs.

Comment: I suggest to use the [nginx::repo](https://github.com/miketheman/nginx/blob/2.7.x/recipes/repo.rb) recipe to use the upstream nginx repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the output says, the following the `nginx` service couldn't be started:

```
STDOUT: Starting nginx: [FAILED]
STDERR: nginx: [emerg] open() "/home/deploy/apps/...-api/shared/log/nginx.access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Make sure that the directory `/home/deploy/apps/...-api/shared/log/` exists and is writeable for Nginx.